# Golang GORM got an Error when manually transaction

Tags: go, go-gorm

I set in my Global config SkipDefaultTransaction to True. How can I use transaction in Create schema?

I tried in https://gorm.io/docs/transactions.html but i got an error "Invalid Transaction"